# Calling callback from node.js native code

Tags: c++, node.js, callback, native, bus-error

I'm writing an add-on for node.js using c++.

here some snippets:

```
class Client : public node::ObjectWrap, public someObjectObserver {
public:
  void onAsyncMethodEnds() {
    Local<Value> argv[] = { Local<Value>::New(String::New("TheString")) };
    this->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 1, argv);
  }
....
private:
  static v8::Handle<v8::Value> BeInitiator(const v8::Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    Client* client = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Client>(args.This());

    client->someObject->asyncMethod(client, NULL);

    return scope.Close(Boolean::New(true));        
  }      

  static v8::Handle<v8::Value> SetCallback(const v8::Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    Client* client = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Client>(args.This());
    client->callback = Persistent<Function>::New(Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]));

    return scope.Close(Boolean::New(true));
  }
```

I need to save a javascript function as callback to call it later. 
The Client class is an observer for another object and the javascript callback should be called from onAsyncMethodEnds.
Unfortunately when I call the function "BeInitiator" I receive "Bus error: 10" error just before the callback Call()

thanks in advice

Comment: Are you calling it in the same thread?

Comment: No.. The "asyncmethod" starts a new thread. This method is part of a lib that I've linked that uses talk_base/thread in order to run asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `->Call` from another thread. JavaScript and Node are single threaded and attempting to call a function from another thread amounts to trying to run two threads of JS at once.

You should either re-work your code to not do that, or you should read up on `libuv`'s threading library. It provides `uv_async_send` which can be used to trigger callback in the main JS loop from a separate thread.

There are docs here: http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html

Comment: I suppose that this resolves the problem. Unfortunately I can't use libuv.. I will try to do the same thing using the Send method of talk_base/thread. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why can't you use `libuv`?

Comment: I ask only because you should have access to it automatically if you are compiling for Node.

Comment: Because the thread was run by an external library that I have linked in to the project. However I have found that uv_send and uv_init work also within "not libuv thread". So thank you.

Comment: Here is a full example https://blog.scottfrees.com/building-an-asynchronous-c-addon-for-node-js-using-nan