# Notifying javascript from a node.js native addon (c++)

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node-gyp

I do not have much knowledge about javascript. I have written in C++ a shared library that does certain things in a daemon thread. I needed this to be invoked from javascript. By using `SWIG` I've successfully able to generate a wrapper and compile my code along with it into `.node` module using node-gyp (wrote binding.gyp for it too). Now i can drop to node prompt and do something like:

```
> var a = require("./module_name")
> a.SomeCppFunction("SomeString")
```

and wonderfully invoke the cpp functions, start a detached thread there and return the control back to javascript. However I want to notify the javascript from the detached cpp thread about stuffs. I tried registering javascript functions by collecting `function() {}` signature types in `void(*fp)()` etc., to call them back later from c++, but that didn't work. Is there anyway to be able to achieve this ie., register javascript functions (or something else) as callback in the cpp code ?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076978/calling-callback-from-node-js-native-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling callback from node.js native code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076978/calling-callback-from-node-js-native-code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling javascript function from C++ Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455816/calling-javascript-function-from-c-addon)

Comment: @EzequielGarcia Thanks for you suggestion but I asked this almost 8 years back :) and haven't dealt with this tech stack for a long time now. So I don't have much idea about what I wanted anymore. If you feel your links sufficiently answers the question, feel free to close it. Otherwise I don't know what SO expects in these scenarios as I don't have much time to try and remember. Maybe post a question and answer yourself and close this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of SWIG and Napi. An existing repo which does this is available [here](https://github.com/flatmax/swig-and-napi), with a blog [here](http://terrawatts.flatmax.com/2022/11/take-swig-and-thread-napi.html). But I'll sum up the process here.

Create your class to use in SWIG, which has a thread running in the threadMain method :

```
#include <Thread.H>

class Test : public ThreadedMethod {

  void *threadMain(void);

public:
  Test();

  void setFnPointer(const char* s);
};
```

Now in the Napi code, you will generate your thread safe function like so :

```
Napi::ThreadSafeFunction tsfn; ///< The node api's threadsafe function

Napi::Value Start( const Napi::CallbackInfo& info ){
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  // Create a ThreadSafeFunction
  tsfn = Napi::ThreadSafeFunction::New(env,
    info[0].As<Napi::Function>(),  // JavaScript function to call
    "Resource Name", 0,1);

  // return the tsfn as a pointer in a string
  char addr[24];
  sprintf(addr,"%p",&tsfn);
  return Napi::String::New(env, addr);
}

// some small code to call NODE_API_MODULE here, check the file NapiCode.C in the repo
```

You compile the SWIG code to one module and the Napi code down to a different module and you pass the thread safe funciton pointer from one to the other like so :

```
var libNapiNodejs = require('../swig/.libs/libNapiNodejs');
let fp = libNapiNodejs.start(function () {
    console.log("JavaScript callback called with arguments", Array.from(arguments));
}, 5);


// SWIG get our C++ and thread running
var libSwigCNodejs = require('../swig/.libs/libSwigCNodejs');
let test = new libSwigCNodejs.Test;

test.setFnPointer(fp); // tell swig the callback function pointer to execute
test.run(); // run the C++ thread in the SWIG module
```

You will see that the C++ thread calls the javascript function. This is what the C++ thread looks like in SWIG :

```
Napi::ThreadSafeFunction *tsfn; ///< The node api's threadsafe function
void *Test::threadMain(void){
  printf("C++ Thread enter %s\n",__func__);
  auto callback = []( Napi::Env env, Napi::Function jsCallback, int* value ) {

    jsCallback.Call( {Napi::Number::New( env, *value )} );
  };

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    sleep(1);
    if (*tsfn) {
      printf("calling tsfn->BlockingCall\n");
      napi_status status = tsfn->BlockingCall( &i, callback );
      if ( status != napi_ok ) // Handle error
        break;
    }
  }
  tsfn->Release();
  printf("C++ Thread exit %s\n",__func__);
  return NULL;
}
```