# Why are my request and response messages out of order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

I'm working through a book that teaches you the basics of Node.JS and I've created a couple of programs - one responder and one requester.

The responder:

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const zmq = require("zmq");
const responder = zmq.socket("rep"); // Create socket to reply to client requests

// Handle incoming requests
responder.on("message", function(data) {
    // Parse incoming message
    let request = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("Received request to get: " + request.path);

    // Read file and reply with content
    fs.readFile(request.path, function(err, content) {
        console.log("Sending response content");
        responder.send(JSON.stringify({
            content: content.toString(),
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            pid: process.pid
        }));
    });
});

// Listen on TCP port 5433
responder.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5433", function(err) {
    console.log("Listening for zmq requesters...");
});

// Close the responder when the Node process ends
process.on("SIGINT", function() {
    console.log("Shutting down...");
    responder.close();
});
```

The requester:

```
"use strict";

const zmq = require("zmq");
const filename = process.argv[2];
const requester = zmq.socket("req"); // Create request endpoint

// Handle replies from responder
requester.on("message", function(data) {
    let response = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("Received response:", response);
});

requester.connect("tcp://localhost:5433");

// Send request for content
for (let i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
    console.log("Sending request " + i + " for " + filename);
    requester.send(JSON.stringify({
        path: filename
    }));
}
```

So I run the responder program which starts up fine, then I run the requester program like this (`target.txt` already exists on the filesystem):

```
> node requester.js target.txt
```

The weird thing is that, given Node.js's single threading, I would expect the output to *always* be:

```
Sending request 1 for target.txt
Sending request 2 for target.txt
Sending request 3 for target.txt
Received response: { ...
```

However, sometimes I get that, but sometimes I'm getting:

```
Sending request 1 for target.txt
Sending request 2 for target.txt
Received response: { ...
Sending request 3 for target.txt
```

How can this be?  The event loop is executing my `for` loop, which should mean that the "Sending request" lines get output, and then it has the opportunity to invoke the response handler.  Why am I sometimes getting a response logged before the third request is logged?

Comment: I think that given the uncertain nature of a network, you shouldn't rely on the order of requests/responses.
You may make request1 now then request2 and request3 but you may get the responses in any order.

Comment: @klikas Do you understand the single-threaded nature of Node.js?

Comment: I do understand that Node.js is single threaded, I just don't know how you can actually ensure that in a real-world scenario, your requests are going to hit your server in a specific order all the time.

Comment: I'd guess that it has something to do with `zmq` containing native code and the semantics being different in that situation. The behaviour suggests that the callback supplied to `on` is being invoked within the `send` implementation if a response is available.

Comment: @cartant That's the only possibility. The callback must be invoked synchronously during a send operation for that to happend.

Comment: @klikas I'm not talking about the order the requests hit the server.  I'm talking about the order in which `console.log` gets called by the requester program.  Surely it *must* call `console.log` 3 times in the `for` loop before the thread gets round to the response callback?

Comment: @cartant That does make sense; so `Received response: { ...` is being logged by a thread that is **not** the Node.js event loop, but a thread that has been created by native ZMQ code?  Could you put that in an answer? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's apparent that the behaviour you are seeing can only occur if the callback supplied to `on` is invoked from within the `send` implementation.

The `zmq` module contains native code. It receives the responses in native code and then makes them available to the JavaScript host. Its receipt of responses is not tied the the JavaScript event loop. It appears that within the `send` implementation, if a response is available, the callback supplied to `on` is invoked. Presumably, any responses not passed to the callback within `send` calls are passed on the next turn through the event loop.

Comment: Or all the responses just bypass the event loop altogether?  If ZMQ is using its own threads to execute the `on("message"...` callback, why does it need to worry about Node.js's event loop at all?

Comment: It cannot execute a JavaScript callback on another thread. The JavaScript is still single-threaded. But from within `send` it can call the callback.

Comment: How can the JavaScript be single-threaded?  While the main event loop is in the middle of logging `Sending request` to the console, ZMQ comes along and logs `Received response` to the console.  Surely that must be a different thread.

Comment: The JavaScript is single threaded. There is some information on JavaScript/native code interop [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17091303/6680611). `send` is invoked on the JavaScript thread and likely does the following: sends the message; checks for any responses received whilst the JavaScript thread was running; if there are any responses, passes them to the `on` callback; and then returns to the calling JavaScript - and continues iterating through your `for` loop.

Comment: That seems like odd and unexpected behaviour.  When I "send", I don't expect it to "send and check for responses and run the callback handler".  I expect it to send, then finish running the rest of my code, then continue running the event loop and *then* callback if any responses were received.  I'm not sure why they designed it the way they did.

Answer (score -1):

When reading a file in your `responder` function you use `fs.readFile` which is a asynchronous non-blocking function (it will read the file in a new thread). This means that it wont wait for the file to be read before it accepts a new request.

If you want to use a synchronous function you can use

```
fs.readFileSync
```

This will wait for the file to be completely read and then send a response.

Comment: That's not my point.  My point is that the requester program is outputting that response to the console *before* it outputs all 3 requests, even though the single-threaded nature of Node.js should mean that it *must* output all 3 requests even if a response arrives in the meantime.

Comment: Maybe I still dont understund. But when you use `fs.readFile` it will do that in a different thread. So depending on how fast it can read the file the order can change.

It could be so that all your request to read the file run at the same time in different threads and then the fastest one will return first